# frank - specifying multiple columns from data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, frank

I am quote confused about the `frank` function. The documentation here says:

> Only for lists, data.frames and data.tables. The columns to calculate
> ranks based on. Do not quote column names. If ... is missing, all
> columns are considered by default. To sort by a column in descending
> order prefix a "-", e.g., frank(x, a, -b, c). The -b works when b is
> of type character as well.

so i have my data:

```
structure(list(product = c("Product 1", "Product 1", "Product 1", 
                           "Product 1", "Product 1", "Product 5", "Product 5", "Product 5", 
                           "Product 5", "Product 5"), policyID = c("A738-33", "A738-33", 
                                                                   "A738-33", "A738-33", "A738-33", "A738-33", "A738-33", 
                                                                   "A738-33", "A738-33", "A738-33"), startYear = c(2014, 
                                                                                                                               2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), total = c("30000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "30000", "30000", "30000", "30000", "10000", "10000", "10000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "10000", "10000"), daily = c("150", "150", "150", "150", "150", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "80", "80", "80", "80", "80")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7feec50126e0>, sorted = "product")
```

I want to order this data by columns `total` and `daily`. So i have done this:

```
> setDT(testDT)
> frankv(testDT, totallimit, rbddaily, ties.method="dense")
Error in colnamesInt(x, cols, check_dups = TRUE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='30000'
```

strangely enough, when i DO use quotations, exactly the opposite what the documentatoin says, I am getting results:

```
frankv(testDT, cols=c("totallimit", "rbddaily"), ties.method="dense")
```

I also tried to integrating thin into data.table, and another weird thing happened. From the 10 rows of data I had, i obtained a 100 rows.

```
testDT[,.(rank = frankv(testDT, cols=c("limit", "daily"), ties.method="dense")), by = c("policyID", "product", "startYear")]
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix this? The documentation is not of much help, maybe i am missing something...

Comment: the colnames used in your code are not matching the ones in your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `frank` you should not quote, but for `frankv` (the function you used) you should:

```
library(data.table)
frank(testDT, total, daily, ties.method="dense")

 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1

frankv(testDT, cols=c("total", "daily"), ties.method="dense")

 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: how come when i use this as `testDT[,.(rank = frank(testDT, totallimit, rbddaily, ties.method="dense")), by = c("policyID", "product", "startYear")]`suddenly i get 100 rows instead of 10?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this line of code?

Comment: i want to add a column to the `data.table` that indicates the rank of products by total and daily for every policy&startyear combination

Comment: oh, i just realized how pointless my attempt was. This is what i wanted to achieve`testDT$rank = frank(testDT, totallimit, rbddaily, ties.method="dense")`